# Mysql update query with multiple order by?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the following query to work as expected? MySQL gives me an error for the multiple `ORDER BY`

```
UPDATE user_list 
SET user_code = $code 
WHERE user_id = $id
AND country = $country AND 
     ((d = $d) OR 
     (c = $c ORDER BY c ASC LIMIT 1) OR
     (b = $b ORDER BY b ASC LIMIT 1))
```

The idea is the following:

If there is a user with `user_id = $id AND country = $country AND d = $d` then `SET user_code = $code`

If the above is false, then go and take **THE 1st user ordered by c** with `user_id = $id AND country = $country AND c = $c` and then do `SET user_code = $code`

If the above is false, then go and take **THE 1st user ordered by b** with `user_id = $id AND country = $country AND b = $b` and then do `SET user_code = $code`

Comment: `ORDER BY` should be at the end of the query, not in the `OR` clause. *I deleted my comment: huge error in it.*

Comment: @ caCtus: I am aware of this, but how can I get it work with 2 order by?

Comment: Could you clarify on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you use Order By for Update? it's used usually for Select statment

Comment: @Mureinik: update if d = $d ELSE update if c = $c ORDER BY c ELSE update if b = $b ORDER BY b

Comment: @Ahmad : Oh right, I didn't see that. I just wrote an horrible thing. :D

Comment: @SpeedCoder still unclear, sorry. Can you share some sample data to and what you're attempting to update it to?

Comment: Perhaps if you coded less speedily...

Comment: @t.niese I think whatever he wants the SQL is invalid, he uses ORDER BY to make a condition, which is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested sql to find the first user ordered by c or b, I modified your original command.

```
UPDATE user_list 
SET user_code = $code 
WHERE user_id = $id
AND country = $country AND 
     ((d = $d) OR 
     ( $c = (select c from user_list order by c asc limit 1)) OR
     ( $b = (select b from user_list order by b asc limit 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to update the row where the maximum value of c or b equals some value.  You can do this with joins:

```
UPDATE user_list u CROSS JOIN
       (select max(c) as maxc, max(b) = maxb
        from user_list
        where user_id = $id AND country = $country
       ) uu
    SET user_code = $code
    WHERE user_id = $id AND country = $country AND
           ((d = $d) OR (c = maxc and c = $c) or (b = maxb and b = $b))
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what those statements do... Is there an easier way to archive what I am trying to do?